# What is the simplest way to reset all staged files in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have used `git reset` before for single files but I frequently find myself having to unstage multiple files before a commit. Is there a command that unstages all staged files? I couldn't find it on the documentation (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Answer (score 11):

`git status` usually shows you the options, e.g.

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   someFile.txt
    modified:   someDir/someOtherFile.txt
```

So if you want to unstage all files just do what git proposes

```
git reset HEAD
```

**EDIT**

Since Git 2.23 you can use [`git restore --staged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/2.25.0). `git restore` can also restore working tree files from another commit (`-s`) and run interactively (`-p`). There are even more interessting options available. See the [`git restore` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/2.25.0).

Comment: `git restore --staged :/` restores all staged files in your work tree to the "unstaged" state. Then `git restore :/` trashes the unstaged changes.  Note that any files that were created with `git mv` will still be there though.

Comment: The comment by @user9645 should be the accepted answer to this question. We're talking about multiple files and how to unstage them in the most simple way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git reset HEAD .
```

Git should actually write what to do, when you execute `git status`

```
6:16:17 {proj_main} ~/git/proj_main$ git status
On branch proj_main
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   sub_proj/.project
```

Comment: Thanks Matej. GIt doesn't give me this option though. I am not sure what happens with my Git but every time there is a merge conflict several files that I didn't even touch show on the staging area, ready to be committed. It is  very strange. I have to unstage those files because I have no idea what Git is doing.

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD` has no effect. Reset soft means that you reset the HEAD to another commit, but not the index nor the working dir. The commit you want to reset the `HEAD` to is `HEAD` in your case. So no effect.

Comment: @René you are right. I checked it again and fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

I use [SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview) client. It has option for Stage and UnStage all files. You can also use it in combination with command line.